# How can I query UserId for AWS SSO Users using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore, aws-sso

How can I get `UserId` for AWS SSO Users using Boto3.

I wanted to use it to assign permissions to a user for a specific aws account using below code, however, this requires `PrincipalId` which is some 16-20 digit number associated with each user and is called `User ID` in the AWS console.

You can read about it - [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html#SSOAdmin.Client.create_account_assignment)

```
response = client.create_account_assignment(
    InstanceArn='string',
    TargetId='string',
    TargetType='AWS_ACCOUNT',
    PermissionSetArn='string',
    PrincipalType='USER'|'GROUP',
    PrincipalId='string'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the UserName for the user you'd like to assign permissions for, you can [programmatically use IAM](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user) to determine that user's UserId:

```py
import boto3

# Get the UserId.
user_name = 'the user name here'
iam_client = boto3.client('iam')
result = iam_client.get_user(UserName=user_name)
user_id = result['User']['UserId']

# Assign permissions to the UserId.
sso_admin_client = boto3.client('sso-admin')
response = sso_admin_client.create_account_assignment(
    InstanceArn='string',
    TargetId='string',
    TargetType='AWS_ACCOUNT',
    PermissionSetArn='string',
    PrincipalType='USER',
    PrincipalId=user_id
)
```

Comment: sso user is not IAM user

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to use the 'identitystore' to get user or group IDs. Try this from the docs -

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('identitystore')

response = client.get_user_id(
    IdentityStoreId='string',
    AlternateIdentifier={
        'ExternalId': {
            'Issuer': 'string',
            'Id': 'string'
        },
        'UniqueAttribute': {
            'AttributePath': 'string',
            'AttributeValue': {...}|[...]|123|123.4|'string'|True|None
        }
    }
)
```

Although I personally found that the above method didn't work for me due to it not being available in my installed version of Boto3, so I did this instead which worked perfectly -

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('identitystore')

response = client.list_users(
    IdentityStoreId='string',
    Filters=[
        {
            'AttributePath': 'UserName',
            'AttributeValue': 'string'
        },
    ]
)

print(response["Users"][0]["UserId"])
```

Sources:

- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore.html#id24
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore.html#IdentityStore.Client.get_user_id
- https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore.html#IdentityStore.Client.list_users